# Google maps geocode returns ZERO_RESULTS for some queries when I use Country Code

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geolocation

I have been working on an application which uses google maps api. recently i found geocoding not compatible with some address like,

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ae

which the address is country code. But it was working properly before. But today
09/08/2017 i found this issue. and additionally I found geolocation also fails to determine the location frequently in official website 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation.

Please guide.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For the searching of the country by its code I would suggest applying [component filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering) instead of the address parameter. It should work better in this use case. Passing country code as address parameter is treated as incomplete street address and the result is prone to be ZERO_RESULTS for incomplete addresses. Change your query to

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country%3AAE&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Regarding to the second issue, this is a bug reported at Chrome issue tracker:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=753242

It looks like Google team has already adjusted the usage quota for the API key that they use internally and solved this issue.